# Not displaying zero values

Tags: powershell, zero

I have PowerShell script and part of it counts the number of lines in a file. If the file has lines it is ok, but if it has no lines it it doesn't show anything in the count value - I need it to show zero.

```
#Count the number of lines that we have so far for KNOWN error_4 types
if (Test-Path $path\known_error_type_4.log) {
  $error_4_measure = Get-Content $path\known_error_type_4.log | Measure-Object
  $error_4_count = @($error_4_measure).Count
  echo "Known Error_4 Type Line count is  : ${error_4_count} lines"
```

I've tried put put it into an array with `@()` as that should return something but I suspect that I've gone slightly wrong but I cant see it.

Comment: Use `Measure-Object -Line` and `$error_4_measure.Lines` to get the count of non-empty lines in the file. See [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13440389/1630171).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the array subexpression operator `@()` around the `Get-Content` statement instead and inspect the `Count` property:

```
$error_4_count = @(Get-Content $path\known_error_type_4.log).Count
```